# Postgresql getting null values when using dynamic keys in jsonb

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js, jsonb

I am using Jsonb to store data into DB so I have a cell which look like this:

```
{country: {
   name: 'country',
   type: ['type', 'type1'],
  },
region: {
  key: ['value']
  },
}
```

I need to access `type` under `country` or `key` under `region`. I want to do this in one query therefore I am using dynamic values.
`...('jsonb_array_elements(data -> ? -> ?',[dynamicObjectName, dynamicKeyName]))`

The problem is that this returns an array of null `[null,null]`

In case I don't use dynamic value for object it does work:
`...('jsonb_array_elements(data -> "country" -> ?',[dynamicKeyName]))` returns `['type', 'type1']`

I really would like to have it flexible, any idea what can be the problem with dynamic objectName ?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with knex.js, but it seems very suspicious to me that you get an array of *two* nulls back. If you add another element to country.type (so it's `['type', 'type1', 'type2']`), do you get back `[null, null, null]`?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working in terms of accessing the right data but then the interpretation of values is somehow wrong. So yes I would get 3 null. For simplicity the value doesn't even  has to be an array so the query would be without the `jsonb_array_elements` but still  the same behavior - throwing null.

Comment: Can you share you knex.js query?